# Clockwise Image swap in Javascript table with one click

Tags: javascript, image, swap

I am attempting to create a table that has 4 images in a random order. When one image is clicked it should move with the image that is clockwise to it. However, When I do this, I have the two diagonal images moving with each other, despite changing the onclick + "clickmove(3)" attributes.

Upon clicking the last slot, the program returns an error and does not move the image indicating that I cannot move above x+1 of the third slot. I tried various methods of fixing this to no avail.

Thank you in advance

```
<html>
<script>

    function clickMove(x)
    {
        var temp;
        d = document.images

        if (d[x].src)
        {
            temp = d[x].src
            d[x].src = d[x + 1].src
            d[x + 1].src = temp
        }
}
    function check(n)
    {
        //d = document.images[n].src

        //alert(s+":"+d.length

        //if (d.charAt(d.length == 1)
    }
</script>


    <head>
        <title> Assignment 4 Kaltenbaugh </title>
    </head>

        <body background = "http://webclass.sru.edu/CPSC-217-01.0118/Kaltenbaugh%20Cain%20%20CXK1047/Assignment3/table1.png">
            <table border = "0" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" align = "center">
                <tr>
                    <td id = "t0"><img src = "http://webclass.sru.edu/CPSC-217-01.0118/Kaltenbaugh%20Cain%20%20CXK1047/Assignment4/treePic_04.jpg" onclick = "clickMove(0)"></td>
                    <td id = "t1"><img src = "http://webclass.sru.edu/CPSC-217-01.0118/Kaltenbaugh%20Cain%20%20CXK1047/Assignment4/treePic_03.jpg" onclick = "clickMove(1)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id = "t2"><img src = "http://webclass.sru.edu/CPSC-217-01.0118/Kaltenbaugh%20Cain%20%20CXK1047/Assignment4/treePic_02.jpg" onclick = "clickMove(3)"></td>
                    <td id = "t3"><img src = "http://webclass.sru.edu/CPSC-217-01.0118/Kaltenbaugh%20Cain%20%20CXK1047/Assignment4/treePic_01.jpg" onclick = "clickMove(2)"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When x is 3, x + 1 is 4, which is out of bounds. While x + 1 is OK when x is 0, 1 or 2, you want to swap image 3 with image 0.

There a number of ways you could do this, one of them being to replace `x + 1` with `(x + 1) % 4`.

```
    if (d[x].src)
    {
        temp = d[x].src
        d[x].src = d[(x + 1) % 4].src
        d[(x + 1) % 4].src = temp
    }
```

Edit: I'd assumed in the above example that you'd basically wanted the x + 1, but that you just needed to fix the wrap-around problem. As for the clockwise issue, think of it this way:

```
0 1
2 3
```

0 should swap with 1, 1 should swap with 3, 2 should swap with 0, and 3 should swap with 2. Just make a little table out of those relationships.

```
    if (d[x].src)
    {
        var y = [1, 3, 0, 2][x];
        temp = d[x].src;
        d[x].src = d[y].src;
        d[y].src = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify how this is to be implemented? Would it go right into the swap function? Or would it have to be a separate if statement? The modulus does not seem to be affecting my standard swap statement

Comment: I updated my answer showing the change more explicitly.

Comment: Haha yeah i actually figured that part out apologies for making you do the extra work. However, I still run into the problem that the images are swapping diagonally and am currently looking into it. Thank you

Comment: I hadn't been thinking about the clockwise movement issue, just solving the index-out-of-bounds problem that first jumped out at me. I've made another update for the clockwise movement problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually managed to figure it out another way with the help of the out of bounds method. Appreciate the help! Have a good day!